# Conditional ExecutionHandler in pipeline

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, pipeline

The server I'm developing has different tasks to perform based on messages received from clients, some tasks are very simple and require little time to perform, but other may take a while.

Adding an ExecutionHandler to the pipeline seems like a good solution for the complicated tasks  but I would like to avoid threading simple tasks.

My pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MessageDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MessageEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("executor", this.executionHandler);
pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerHandler(this.networkingListener));
```

Where MessageEncoder returns a Message object (for `decode`) which defines the requested task.

Is there a way to skip the execution handler based on the decoded message?
The question can be generalized to: is there a way to condition whether or not the next handler will be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ExecutionHandler` as is, you can extend it to override its `handlerUpstream()` method to intercept the upstream events and call `ctx.sendUpstream(e)` for the `MessageEvent`s whose message meets your criteria.  All other events could be handled by the `ExecutionHandler` via `super.sendUpstream(e)`.  That is:

```
public class MyExecutionHandler extends ExecutionHandler {
    public void handleUpstream(ctx, evt) throws Exception {
        if (evt instanceof MessageEvent) {
            Object msg = ((MessageEvent) evt).getMessage();
            if (msg instanceof ExecutionSkippable) {
                ctx.sendUpstream(evt);
                return;
            }
        }

        super.handleUpstream(evt);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it (or add it on demand) from the pipeline inside your MessageDecoder before you send the message upstream. You can also check the message inside your executionHandler and just pass it upstream. 
In case you cannot modify these two files you can create another handler which removes executionHandler based on the message type.

Comment: I understand that from the `MessageDecoder.decode` method I can get the pipeline from the `ChannelHandlerContext` and remove/add the `ExecutionHandler`, but I would rather deal with that logic in the `ExecutionHandler` itself, how can that be done? Probably by overriding `handleUpstream`, but how should I implement it? just return in case it's a simple task?