# Netty - Continue processing message via ExecutionHandler.handleUpstream

Tags: netty

I need to be able to isolate certain processing in a separate thread.  Only certain messages require this extra processing.  It does involve a native call and remote resources; thus, I really want to be able to tightly control this processing using my own threadpool/queue.

My initial implementation uses a ThreadPoolExecutor which is accessible from my ChannelHandler.  Once my handler identifies a message that requires special handling, I submit my Worker to the Executor for processing.  Note, I did see the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593192/conditional-executionhandler-in-pipeline/14597416#14597416) about extending the ExecutionHandler and filtering at that point, but think I would still have the same issue.

**The issue being** that after the worker process completes, I would like the message to continue in the ExecutionHandler/ThreadPool defined in my pipeline.  Thus, freeing up the "worker" thread; again the worker threadpool has tight restrictions in terms of queue size, max threads, etc.

Below is my Worker (inner class of my ChannleHandler).  Towards the bottom, I get the ExecutionHandler used in the pipeline and call the handleUpstream method.  Seems to work for me, but wondering if there are any hidden issues that I am not considering...

```
public class EncryptionWorker implements Runnable
{
    private ChannelHandlerContext _ctx;
    private MessageEvent _e;

    public EncryptionWorker(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        _e = e;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Object m = _e.getMessage();
        if ( !( m instanceof AESSLMessageCtx ) )
        {            
            LOGGER.error( "Invalid Message sent to EncryptionWorker.");
            return;
        }
        AESSLMessageCtx msgContext = (AESSLMessageCtx) m;

        LOGGER.info( "EncryptionWorker initiated, id: " + msgContext.getIdentifier());

        // TODO - Process the  Message.      
        try 
        {
            // Encryption needs to be isolated from main pipeline.
            // Only occurs for special messages; could block for
            // a period of time; do not want it affecting normal
            // traffic.
            //.......
            Thread.sleep( 2000 );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LOGGER.warn( "Exception processing encrypted message, id: " +  msgContext.getIdentifier(), ex );
            sendError( _ctx.getChannel(), msgContext, TxnMessageCtx.ErrorReason.SYSLEVEL_ERROR );
            return;
        }

        // Continue processing message as normal....
        // Do not want to do "_ctx.sendUpstream( _e )"
        // because it continues to use my EncryptionWorker Thread.
        // I would rather do something like the following in order to
        // get it back into service pipeline Executor Threadpool.

        // Get ExecutionHandler being used in pipeline.
        ChannelHandler ch = _ctx.getPipeline().get( "executor" );
        if (ch == null || !(ch instanceof ExecutionHandler))
        {
            LOGGER.error( "ExecutionHandler not found.");
            return;                
        }
        ExecutionHandler execHandler = (ExecutionHandler) ch;

        try
        {
            // Use ExecutionHandler Executor to continue processing
            execHandler.handleUpstream( _ctx, _e );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LOGGER.error( "Exception initiating upstream handling after encryption processing, tpdu: " + txnContext.getIdentifier(), ex );
            sendError( _ctx.getChannel(), msgContext, TxnMessageCtx.ErrorReason.SYSLEVEL_ERROR );
            return;                
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the ExecutionHandler extension solution wouldn't work. If you have a handler chain: first -> encryption-handler -> executor-handler, encryption handler can handle specific messages and pass on the others to executor-handler.

Comment: Sorry for late response, didn't even realize there was a comment posted…  When you say "Execution extension", I assume you are referencing the solution in the other post that I referenced above.  Isn't that solution just determining whether the next Handler gets executed by the Executor or continues in the current thread? (e.g. regardless the next handler would execute)

Comment: Also note, I really want to isolate that encryption work (e.g. the work done by the EncryptionWorker above).  When it works, it is sub-second response time, but when things go bad, it can really go bad (e.g. 10-20 second response times).  I don't want it effecting normal traffic what so ever, and I basically want to start rejecting encrypted traffic (e.g. thread pool at max limit, queue maxed out).

Comment: Encryption handler has an Executor, and executor handler has another executor. They are totally isolated and have different characteristics. If the encryption handler decides to process a messsage, the message will be delivered to the execution handler when encryption work completes, and processed on a thread that belongs to the execution handler.

Comment: Ahhhh, think I'm getting it now, so just have an ExecutionHandler in my pipeline after my encryption handler.  Encryption Handler continues to process using it's own Executor, then sends the results upstream which is another ExecutionHandler; thus releasing my Encryption Thread... I'll give it a try, thanks!!!